# How to display taxonomy terms in block, drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

I've a taxonomy vocabulary

```
voca1
-item 1.1
--item 1.1.1
--item 1.1.2
--item 1.1.3
-item 1.2
--item 1.2.1
--item 1.2.2
--item 1.2.3
--item 1.2.4
--item 1.2.5
--item 1.2.6
-item 1.3
--item 1.3.1
--item 1.3.2
--item 1.3.3
```

when user click voca1, I want to display the terms by following at page.

```
item 1.1
item 1.1.1                 item 1.1.2                      item 1.1.3


item 1.2
item 1.2.1                 item 1.2.2                      item 1.2.3
item 1.2.4                 item 1.2.5                      item 1.2.6


item 1.3
item 1.3.1                 item 1.3.2                      item 1.3.3
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i guess what you are looking for is [taxonomy_term_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) function, dig it you will find your way out.